# SVN: How to get files added to svn and not committed

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have added a file (say SomeFile.cs) to a specific folder. I did not commit as I wanted to do commit at once after achieving the functionality. An svn update worked just fine on this until someone changed the folder name and changed the names of files under it.

Now the next day when I did svn checkout, resulted in tree level conflicts, so I copied my newly added files to this "new" location and did as "Resolve using theirs".

The resolve deleted all my local files and replaced with new folder and files. I could not find my local files (which were in my working copy) in my entire computer (includint recycle bin).

Now is there at least an option to retrieve the files which were added ("Add" option) to svn and NOT committed to svn using "Commit"?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, only files committed to svn will be recoverable. But if you merge the conflict with theirs, then it would have overriden the changes locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Update to revision", but as your files were NOT committed it will most likely restore your directory structure in best case scenario.
Generally "Resolve using theirs" option is an equivalent of saying "I screwed up, they are right" -> whatever I have is wrong, and what they have is right -> overwrite my copy.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is pretty much against the workflow of SVN.  Things don't get stored in the repository until they are committed, and are thus not "safe".  You are supposed to commit often.

If you are trying to work but worried about other people's tree changes getting in your way, consider making a branch.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html

However, SVN should never overwrite files in your local working copy that have modifications.  If you do an svn update, and someone has added/changed something, you will get a "conflict", which you will have to resolve manually.  You resolved these conflicts manually, and accidentally overwrote you work.  This is why you should commit often.  Anything you commit can be recovered.